# Changing a LinearLayout height dynamically

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to change the height of a `LinearLayout` height dynamically during the app run but I always get a `NullPointerException`. I tried the handler with:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new linearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
```

I also tried to change the layout color and got the same error.
any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,100); 
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
```

Comment: This what i wrote trying with thread (one of many ideas i tried ):

    (new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            //Ta.setBackgroundColor(color);
    Ta.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,taille));
           }
    }).start();

Comment: you are trying to do that from a thread? from what i know it's impossible to change UI not from the UI thread. So all you UI manipulation have to be made in the same thread.

Comment: as I told you I tried with a handler too but got the same error

Comment: it's impossible to help you when you keep saying "same error" without showing the actual error... what is you logcat showing?

Comment: here is the logcat:03-06 00:53:06.819: E/AndroidRuntime(364): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
03-06 00:53:06.819: E/AndroidRuntime(364): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 00:53:06.819: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at com.example.appui.MainActivity$3$1.run(MainActivity.java:114)

Comment: I mean past all you logcat output at the moment of the crash in a code block in your question so it could be easily readable.

Comment: that's all the logcat at the moment of the crash :s

Comment: Ta.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,taille));

Comment: it's always the line updating layout parameters, this one for the height and Ta.setBackgroundColor(color) for the color

Comment: are you positive that Ta and taille are not Null?

Comment: the Ta is the linear layout and taille is an integer got from an editText

Comment: you are a getting a NullPointerException, one of the objects you are using have to be Null.

Comment: the thing is if insert the layout without updating anythin in its parameters, it's inserted without a pb, and the taille is an integer as i told you given by the user in an editText so i'm really confused about this situation . How normally do you do to change linear layout parameters?

Comment: how are you passing the intenger from the textview?

Comment: String value = input.getText().toString();
int taille = Integer.parseInt(value);
setColumnParts(taille); In setColumnParts methode there is the code i sent before

Comment: ah by the way if put a.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,50)); for exemple i got same error

Comment: for what i know to get the Integer you have to:  Integer.valueOf(string);

Comment: valueOf and parseInt do the same thing